# How to return a value's for AM/PM in console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log, togglebutton

I have a set of Time with switch button for AM and PM, however when submitting a form, the value's for AM or PM does not exist in browser console.log. Console.log results just blank.

OR you have any ideas as alternate way to allow user to select a time with AM/PM.

My Code as below.

```js
var toggle = document.getElementById('container');
var toggleContainer = document.getElementById('toggle-container');
var toggleNumber;

toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
  toggleNumber = !toggleNumber;
  if (toggleNumber) {
    toggleContainer.style.clipPath = 'inset(0 0 0 50%)';
    toggleContainer.style.backgroundColor = '#D74046';
  } else {
    toggleContainer.style.clipPath = 'inset(0 50% 0 0)';
    toggleContainer.style.backgroundColor = 'dodgerblue';
  }
  console.log(toggleNumber)
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <select id="time" class="form-control">
      <option value=""> Hour </option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      ...
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 mb-20">
    <div class="onoffswitch">
      <input type="checkbox" name="ampm" class="onoff-checkbox" id="ampm">
      <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="ampm">
       <span id="am" class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
       <span id="pm" class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My understanding is that your are expecting the style changes to toggle when the user clicks the checkbox?

Comment: exactly no, in my page already appear toggle button. However, when submitting the form, the value either AM or PM is not existing in console.log

Comment: Than check the 'Persist Logs' in your browser inspector...